# Table filling div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I am trying to make a simple interactive calendar.  Initially I would like for just the months to show, but when the mouse hovers over a month, I would like all the individual days to show up.  Eventually, I would like to be able to click on each day to view that day's content.

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/r8orrebk/

html:

```
<div id = "calendar">
<div class="month">
    January
    <table class="days">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>31</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="month">February</div>
<div class="month">March</div>
<div class="month">April</div>
<div class="month">May</div>
<div class="month">June</div>
<div class="month">July</div>
<div class="month">August</div>
```

css:

```
.days {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.month {
    width: 24%;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}
.month:hover > .days {
    display: block;
}
```

What would be the best approach to accomplish this?  I just started working with HTML and CSS, so I don't even know if using a table would be a good idea.  Unlike what I have now, I want the days to fill up the whole month div.

Should I use javascript/jquery instead of hover in CSS?

Also, is there a way that I could make one month worth of days and just use that for each month, or would I need to make a div or td for each day like I have now?

Thank you.

Comment: For something of this scope, I recommend using an existing library like [this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or [this](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/).

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I'm not entirely sure how to explain it, but the calendar IS the whole site I'm planning on making.  I want the calendar to span the entire screen.  I don't think a plugin would be right choice here.

Comment: FullCalendar is a full-screen plugin, but I understand that sometimes the requirements are such that you have to roll your own. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Answer (score 0):

When `.days` activates and is `display:block`, it defaults to 100% wide. That's how block displays work.

You can fix it by setting the display to table instead of block:

```
.month:hover > .days {
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: How would I go about making this table span the entire div that it is in?